# How to restrict input number to non-decimal

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, validation, numbers

I have a number input on a page, and I want it restricted to whole number values, no decimals.  I am using forms and angularjs for validation.  What do I have to do to make decimals not allowed?  I tried setting step to 1, but this changed nothing.  Many other issues discuss getting browsers to support decimals - I seem to be having the opposite problem.

Comment: use javascript to capture keystroke inside the textarea in question and prevent "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom directive for that, incorporating the [ngModelController.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)
Like this: [Proof of Concept](http://jsfiddle.net/06Lzfms8/)

```
    module.directive("noDecimalInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require:"ngModel",
        link: function(scope,element,attr,ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
                if(value.indexOf(".")>-1) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("notDecimal",false);
                    return undefined;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity("notDecimal",true);
                return value;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So this works beautifully when your input is text, but I could not get it to work when the input was number.  How would the directive differ in that case?  I don't immediately see why there is any difference.

Comment: my guess is, that in case the input is "number", the value, that gets into the parser is not a string anymore, so String Operations like "index.of" are not possible. You should convert the value into string before doing operations on it and afterwards, you could parseFloat(value) it back into a Number type.

Comment: For number, you can do the check `value % 1 !== 0`, which will check for decimal values, but will also allow things such as `1.` and `1.0`