# Transform input field value to decimal

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking for some method or AngularJS directive to support decimal numbers in HTML input forms.

I've a input field that should have maximum two decimals. Currently I've these requirements when leaving the input field:

1. "100" => "100.00"
2. "100.333" => "100.33"
3. "100,33" => "100.33"

If I enter a text-string (not a number), the field must be invalid.

I havn't been able to find a method that solve my issue. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You've asked about AngularJS, but you haven't shown us any of your markup. Please do.

Comment: If you want to operate directily on the input field then you will need to build a directive and access your ng-model inside the directive.

Comment: you can use ngkeyup and make a simple function in your js file to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use the [FCSA number directive](https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number) to control the input in my HTML input fields.

```
<input type='text' ng-model='myNumber' fcsa-number="{ min: 0, max: 100, maxDecimals: 2 }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

[**More details**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

Comment: How can I combine that with a HTML input field? I think your snippet is more for displaying the value.

Comment: just do this {{100.333 | number:3 }} and you get your required output

Comment: Yes, if I would like to display the value from the input field somewhere else. But I would like to update the text inside the input field based on my rules.

Answer (score -2):

Check this out
[How to restrict input number to non-decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042346/how-to-restrict-input-number-to-non-decimal/27053593#comment42888745_27053593)

This should get you the idea for it

regards

**Edit**

If you are not into clicking links:
This should get you the idea

You can make a custom directive for that, incorporating the [ngModelController.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)
Like this: [Proof of Concept](http://jsfiddle.net/06Lzfms8/)

```
    module.directive("noDecimalInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require:"ngModel",
        link: function(scope,element,attr,ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value){
                if(value.indexOf(".")>-1) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("notDecimal",false);
                    return undefined;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity("notDecimal",true);
                return value;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered appropriate on SO.

Comment: okey, next time, i copy and paste my own answer instead of linking it

Comment: Feel free to improve this answer by posting the relevant content from that page.

Comment: if your linked answer addresses this question then I think the appropriate course is to vote to close this question as a duplicate of the question you previously answered. that links the answered question to this one and should get your original answer more views. If people tell you to copy the content over I think that's bad advice.